# "Could not allocate arena" after adding Bluetooth functions to voice recognition code

Tags: tensorflow, bluetooth, esp32, voice-recognition, platformio

I am trying to make a Bluetooth speaker controlled by voice commands. I have successfully written code to connect to the speaker via Bluetooth. Then I have successfully trained a neural network and got the speaker to recognize my commands (Speaker has a microphone). I followed this tutorial and code: https://github.com/atomic14/voice-controlled-robot/tree/main/firmware.
However, when I try to combine the two codes together, I get a "could not allocate arena" error and the code doesn't run properly. All I did was add "#include <btAudio.h>", "btAudio audio = btAudio("ESP_Speaker");", and "audio.begin();" to the main file of the voice recognition code. I have attached code for the main file. All of the other files are pretty much unchanged. In addition, I've attached a picture of the output after the program uploads: [Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dDOH.png). Does anyone have an idea on how I should approach fixing this error? Thank you.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "I2SMicSampler.h"
#include "ADCSampler.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "CommandDetector.h"
#include "CommandProcessor.h"
#include <btAudio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <esp_avrc_api.h>

btAudio audio = btAudio("ESP_Speaker");

// i2s config for using the internal ADC
i2s_config_t adcI2SConfig = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX | I2S_MODE_ADC_BUILT_IN),
    .sample_rate = 16000,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
    .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_LSB,
    .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
    .dma_buf_count = 4,
    .dma_buf_len = 64,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = false,
    .fixed_mclk = 0};

// This task does all the heavy lifting for our application
void applicationTask(void *param)
{
  CommandDetector *commandDetector = static_cast<CommandDetector *>(param);

  const TickType_t xMaxBlockTime = pdMS_TO_TICKS(100);
  while (true)
  {
    // wait for some audio samples to arrive
    uint32_t ulNotificationValue = ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, xMaxBlockTime);
    if (ulNotificationValue > 0)
    {
      commandDetector->run();
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  audio.begin();
  delay(1000);
  
  Serial.println("Starting up");

  // make sure we don't get killed for our long running tasks
  esp_task_wdt_init(10, false);

  // start up the I2S input (from either an I2S microphone or Analogue microphone via the ADC)
#ifdef USE_I2S_MIC_INPUT
  // Direct i2s input from INMP441 or the SPH0645
  I2SSampler *i2s_sampler = new I2SMicSampler(i2s_mic_pins, false);
#else
  // Use the internal ADC
  I2SSampler *i2s_sampler = new ADCSampler(ADC_UNIT_1, ADC_MIC_CHANNEL);
#endif
  // the command processor
  CommandProcessor *command_processor = new CommandProcessor();

  // create our application
  CommandDetector *commandDetector = new CommandDetector(i2s_sampler, command_processor);

  // set up the i2s sample writer task
  TaskHandle_t applicationTaskHandle;
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(applicationTask, "Command Detect", 8192, commandDetector, 1, &applicationTaskHandle, 0);

  // start sampling from i2s device - use I2S_NUM_0 as that's the one that supports the internal ADC
#ifdef USE_I2S_MIC_INPUT
  i2s_sampler->start(I2S_NUM_0, i2sMemsConfigBothChannels, applicationTaskHandle);
#else
  i2s_sampler->start(I2S_NUM_0, adcI2SConfig, applicationTaskHandle);
#endif
}

void loop()
{  
  vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
}
```